# How to get character wise confidence values in tesseract - c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

Im building an application to do OCR on images. I got everything to work but I'm unable to get the confidence values for each character in a word. I can get the confidence values of the word.

This is the code I tried to get confidence for each character:

```cs
using (ResultIterator iter = doocr.GetIter())
{
  iter.Begin();
  do
  {
    listBox1.Items.Add("Char Confidence" + iter.GetConfidence(PageIteratorLevel.Word).ToString());
  } while (iter.Next(PageIteratorLevel.Symbol));
}
```

It always shows a single value of 0 even if there are multiple characters.
`GetIter()` is a function in my class which returns `page.GetIterator()`.

How to get the confidence values for each character? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that initializing tesseract in a different class and then calling iterator in a form gives null result. I began the iteration in the class itself and saved it in a list and then read the list in the form to get the result I want.